# python тесты API. сервер принимает токен авторизации и айди файла, который нужно скачать. как скачать на жесткий диск сам файл? спасибо

Tags: python, api, post, requests

```
import requests

def test_download():
        headers = {"Authorization": "token"}
        data = {"fileId": "43232-31621-51923-31515-59031"}
        responce = requests.post("url/file/download/fileId",headers=headers, json=data)
        # with open("download_file.txt") as code: code.write(responce.content)
        print(responce.text)
        assert responce.status_code == 200
```

Comment: Чтобы записать в файл, нужно как минимум открывать в режиме записи. Ну и т.к. response.content - это байты, то открывать тоже нужно в бинарном режиме.`with open("download_file.txt", "wb") as code: code.write(responce.content)`

Comment: спасибо Вам, теперь файл сохраняется, но текст в нем: не удается получить ответ от сервиса))

Comment: чтобы сохранило файлом, нужно заменить as code: code.write(responce.content) на as file: file.write(resp.content)

Answer (score 0):

чтобы сохранило файлом, нужно заменить as code: code.write(responce.content) на as file: file.write(resp.content)
Для меня это оказалось решением